# Rails 3.2: It is possible to remove Jquery gem and load it from an external source in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm working on a site in Ror 3.2.13 in which each page will have different "application.js" if i may present it like this.
But i want to the content of theses "applications.js" (which will have a diffent name of course) to be as minimal as possible. All will use Jquery and other common librairies so i don't want Jquery compiled to it. and i want to download it manually in the html page.

is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surely possible. Just remove the line from `Gemfile` and then download the jQuery, put in your vendor directory and include your manifest files as needed.

```
//= require PATH_TO_YOUR_JQUERY.JS
```

Replace `PATH_TO_YOUR_JQUERY.JS` with your appropriate library path in your `vendor` directory.

However, you don't need to remove the gem for ensuring you use it only when needed rather you keep the gem and include it `//= require jquery` when needed. This will make it easy to maintain versions.

Comment: Thanks that responds perfecty to my needs, except maybe that one. Is it possible to load Jquery from an external source like google deposit.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this in the manifest file. However, you can easily do that in the template using `<%= javascript_include_tag "JS_URL" %>`